# Why is it that Nightmare works fine with a specific site but when I try with another one, it shows an error?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, wait

I wrote test for my code using Mocha. I have an error when I use a Vimeo link, but when I try a YouTube link, it works fine.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('test vimeo search results', function() {
    it('check the link address', function() {
        this.timeout(120000);
        var nightmare = Nightmare()
        return nightmare
            .goto('https://vimeo.com/12643301')
            .scrollTo(10000,0)
            .wait('#comment-section-renderer-items')
            .evaluate(function () {
                return document.location.toString();
            })
            .end()
            .then(function(link) {
                expect(link).to.equal('https://vimeo.com/12643301');
            })
    });
});
```

It shows me the error

> Error: .wait() timed out after 30000msec

Comment: What is the error that it shows?

Comment: I edited this Error: .wait() timed out after 30000msec

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you wait on the same selector in both cases, there is no reason that both websites will have the same selector id's for comment section for example. Thus when you wait on non-existent selector you get timed-out.

You can find a selector id by inspecting(Ctrl-Shift-I) the Vimeo html page.

Answer (score -1):

Your timeout is not long enough you should wait at least 200000 seconds,
and then if its not working try change the evaluation to check for the query selector of "#comment-section-renderer-items"